# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(objects)

Tags: c#-4.0, jsonconverter

DeserializeObject for  {
"15 Days": "675",
"180 Days": "8100",
"30 Days": "1350",
"60 Days": "2700",
"90 Days": "4050"
}

Comment: I could not deserialize this one as the class object property cannot be started with numerical and space between them. It would be great of you if it could be solved.

Comment: It would be great if we could arrange these values into an array separated by comma ',' like a[id1]="15 Days_675".

Comment: I tried, but no luck. This will take time to research. But good question.

Comment: Can we use it in array?

Comment: yes, we can convert to dictionary

Comment: you use dictionary instead of array. I have answer to convert into dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert this json to dictionary. and this way around to handle this case. As we can directly deserialize to class object.

```
var test = "{ \"15 Days\": \"675\", \"180 Days\": \"8100\", 
\"30 Days\": \"1350\", \"60 Days\": \"2700\", \"90 Days\": 
\"4050\" }";
        string [] json = test.Replace("{", 
string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty).Split(',');
        Dictionary<string, string> jsonDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < json.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] jsonItem = json[i].Split(':');
            jsonDic.Add(jsonItem[1], jsonItem[0]);
        }
```

this dictionary jsonDic will look like below.

[image]

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thank you, ManojKS Ji, it had worked for me, as I have implemented.

Comment: Great, please don't mind to mark as answer for this question. This will motivate to work more on queries.